# Codeigniter file upload failing

Tags: codeigniter, upload

I have an form which allows file uploads. It adds to the database fine, but it doesn't save the file to the specified folder. My view and model code is below (my controller just check to see if the file is set then proceeds to the upload)

View:

```
<form action="admin/admin_area/save_personnel" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="add_personnel">
    <input type="file" name="offshore_medical_certificate" />
</form>
```

Controller:

```
function uploadOffshoreMedical($uid)
{   
    $status = "";
    $msg = "";
    $file_element_name = 'offshore_medical_certificate';
    $certificate_name = 'Offshore Medical';
    if ($status != "error")
    {
        $config['upload_path'] = './certificate_files/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'pdf|doc|docx|txt|png|gif|jpg|jpeg|';
        $config['max_size']  = 1024 * 8;
        $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if (!$this->upload->do_upload($file_element_name))
        {
            $status = 'error';
            $msg = $this->upload->display_errors();
        }
        else
        {
            $data = $this->upload->data();
            $file_id = $this->saveCertificate($uid, $data['raw_name'], $data['file_ext'], $certificate_name);
        }
        if($file_id)
        {
            $status = "success";
            $msg = "File successfully uploaded";
        }
        else
        {
            unlink($data['full_path']);
            $status = "error";
            $msg = "Something went wrong when saving the file, please try again.";
        }

        @unlink($_FILES[$file_element_name]);
    }   
    echo json_encode(array('status' => $status, 'msg' => $msg));
}
```

I have the correct file name from the form, the file I'm uploading is the correct size and the correct file extension. I'm working from localhost so the folders permissions are fine, but for some reason it just isn't working. I have done something similar on another project recently, but I can't seem to find the problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

If I print $data I get the following

```
Array ( [file_name] => 08f8ce288e45207735bdb3f0c3139a0a.txt [file_type] => text/plain [file_path] => C:/wamp/www/marine/certificate_files/ [full_path] => C:/wamp/www/marine/files/08f8ce288e45207735bdb3f0c3139a0a.txt [raw_name] => 08f8ce288e45207735bdb3f0c3139a0a [orig_name] => license.txt [client_name] => license.txt [file_ext] => .txt [file_size] => 2.44 [is_image] => [image_width] => [image_height] => [image_type] => [image_size_str] => ) 

{"status":"error","msg":"Something went wrong when saving the file, please try again."}
```

Comment: Looks like `$this->saveCertificate()` is failing; can we see it? Are you returning something from it?

Comment: As stormdrain says, `$this->saveCertificate()` is failing. Although what appears to be happening is that `$this->upload->do_upload($file_element_name)` fails, so the `$file_id` is never set, and thus `$this->saveCertificate()` fails. Your `$msg` variable is also being overwriting, so your not seeing the error returned from `$this->upload->display_errors()`; If you remove the second if/else statement (`if($file_id){...`), you should see an error for why the file isn't being uploaded.
 ' .

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use Uploadify http://www.uploadify.com

It's a very easy to use jQuery plugin with amazing documentation. I started using it since I began coding and never had any issues.

This way you can easily resolve your issues with both projects.